# android determine which Activity to start

Tags: android, android-activity

I have multiple Activities, but only one of them should be launched depending on the time of day (or night) when user starts the app. Is there any way to check the time and launch the appropriate Activity immediately after app launch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably have to launch a default activity with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"` which will launch the correct activity. and call `finish()` just after.

Answer (score 1):

Have starter Activity do something like:

```
public static enum Time {MORNING,OTHER} //--define more times

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    switch (decideTime()){
        case MORNING:
            startActivity(new Intent(com.some.Activity1.class));
            break;
        case OTHER:
            startActivity(new Intent(com.some.Activity2.class));
            break;
        //--add more cases--
    }
    finish();

}

private Time decideTime(){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    if(hour >= 6 && hour < 12){
        return Time.MORNING;
    }else {
           return Time.OTHER;
    }
    //-- add more checks--
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new activity with feature NO_HISTORY, category launcher activity. Let decide which activity run in OnCreate (startActivity)